# Finding all the rational roots of $25x^3+25x^2-x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Finding all the rational roots of $25x^3+25x^2-x-1$.

So, I saw right away that $-1$ was a root. I then used synthetic division to factor this as:

$(25x^2-1)(x+1)$.

Then I found the roots to $25x^2-1$ as $\frac{1}{5},\frac{-1}{5}$.

I've been telling my precalculus class that once you know the roots you know the factors, and if you know the factors you know the roots. However, in this case the original polynomial does not equal $(x+1)(x-\frac{1}{5})(x+\frac{1}{5})$. Can somebody tell me exactly what went wrong here? Thanks!!

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371021/factoring-3x24x-4-0-using-the-quadratic-formula)

Comment: The product of factors of the form $x-a$ over roots $a$ gives you a [monic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) scaling of the polynomial, not the general polynomial.

Comment: Because it equals $25(x+1)(x-\frac{1}{5})(x+\frac{1}{5})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, the fundamental theorem of algebra admits a leading coefficient. Let's be more explicit. Say a polynomial $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots a_1 x + a_0$ has the roots $r_1, \cdots, r_n$, which may be complex numbers and not necessarily distinct. The leading coefficient, $a_n$, is assumed nonzero.

Then we can write $f$ as a product of linear factors in terms of its roots and its leading coefficient:

$$f(x) = a_n (x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots (x-r_n)$$

This is what you forgot, the leading coefficient. The roots are not sufficient to uniquely determine the polynomial on their own - you can easily see that, however you vary it, the roots would remain the same since $a_n$ is just a constant factor.

---

With this in mind, augmenting your procedure in this example is quite simple. Find the roots of $f(x)$ as you have, and note that the leading coefficient is $25$. Then

$$f(x) = 25(x + 1)\left( x - \frac 1 5 \right)\left( x + \frac 1 5 \right)$$

Of course, that $25$ can be distributed into the rightmost two factors for a nicer presentation if you so choose.

$$f(x) = (x + 1) \cdot 5 \cdot \left( x - \frac 1 5 \right) \cdot 5 \cdot \left( x + \frac 1 5 \right) = (x+1)(5x-1)(5x+1)$$

However this is purely cosmetic and not at all necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially found the factors of $x^3 + x^2-\frac{1}{25}x-\frac{1}{25}$.  You need to multiply your factors by $25$ and appropriately distribute the $5$'s into two of those factors if you want to show that the factors of your original polynomial was $(x+1)(5x-1)(5x+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a polynomial $p$, and $\xi$ is a root of $p$. This means $p(\xi)=0$, but then we also have $c\cdot p(\xi)=0$ for all $c$. In your case you get

$$\frac{1}{25}p(x) = (x+)(x-\frac15)(x+\frac15)$$

for $p(x) = 25x^3+25x^2-x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that factorisation is not correct. There is another factor -- $25$ -- missing.

Actually, your polynomial is immediately factorable by simply using the distributive rule on pairs of terms, in the given order, since we have that the product of two of the terms is the same as the product of the other two terms. Thus we have $$25x^3+25x^2-x-1=25x^2(x+1)-(x+1)=(x+1)(25x^2-1)=25(x+1)\left(x^2-\frac{1}{25}\right)=25(x+1)\left(x-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{5}\right).$$

Answer (score -1):

Simple factorization....
$$
25x^3+25x^2-x-1=25x^2(x+1)-1(x+1)=(x+1)(25x^2-1))
$$
$$
=(x+1)(5x-1)(5x+1)
$$

Comment: @Allawonder: really I  don't understand why this factorization is wrong